# Show div when I scroll past div ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I think this is a pretty straight forward question, but I could not find the correct answer I'm looking for on here. So please forgive me if this question has been asked before.

I have a section `section id="front-page-item-4"`. And in this `section` I have a div called `about-us-short`. What I would like is to have the div `about-us-short` `fade-in` when you scroll past `front-page-item-4`. I found this piece of code, but this just fades the div `about-us-short` in, and not when I scroll past `front-page-item-4`.

What am I doing wrong? It looks like this code is looking for the `height` of the div `front-page-item-4` but I don't know the height of this div nor the offset...

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    var topDivHeight = $("#front-page-item-4").height();
    var viewPortSize = $(window).height();

    var triggerAt = 150;
    var triggerHeight = (topDivHeight - viewPortSize) + triggerAt;

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= triggerHeight) {
        $('.about-us-short').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn();
        $(this).off('scroll');
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help in advance...

Comment: scrollTop is the position of the scroll bar. essentially you want triggerHeight to be the value of scrollTop that you want the about-us-short to fadeIn. Currently it looks like your triggerHeight is negative

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 great, got it to work. `var triggerAt = 1500;` did the trick. Do you know if this will work for all displays (phones, smaller screens). Or should I put a variable here?

Comment: the point of all the computation was to determine how far from the top of the webpage your "front-page-item-4" is.. which may change when on a smaller display. hope that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elegant solution would be if you get dynamically the offset top of the specific div, in your case `#front-page-item-4`. Then you could check in the `$(window).scroll()` method if the offset top of the element has been reached. If yes fade your desired div `about-us-short` in.

To get the offset of an element you can make use of the jQuery [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method.

**HTML**

```
<section id="first">
  <h1>First</h1>
</section>

<section id="second">
  <h1>Second</h1>
  <div id="show">Second div reached. Show me</div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#first{
  height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}

#second{
  height: 800px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

#show{
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var offsetTop = $("#second").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop > offsetTop){
    $("#show").fadeIn(200);
  }
});
```

```js
var offsetTop = $("#second").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrollTop > offsetTop) {
    $("#show").fadeIn(200);
  }
});
```

```css
#first {
  height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}
#second {
  height: 800px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="first">
  <h1>First</h1>
</section>

<section id="second">
  <h1>Second</h1>
  <div id="show">Second div reached. Show me</div>
</section>
```